# Selenium: precision of move_to_element ? It doesn't trigger mouse hover on small elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having this issue with `move_to_element` on small elements (dots in a graph) to trigger the mouse over that brings up a tooltip:

If I just move to an element that is ~1.5 pixels round, it fails 20-30% of the time.

I ended up writing a small hack script, spiraling around the element until I hit it and it works 100% of the time, but it's kinda slow.
It consistently seem to find the element about +2,+2 pixels away when not found at first.

To me that just says that the `move_to_element` function is just not precise enough. 
From the doc it says it defaults to the center of the element.

When I look up the element in Chrome dev tools, the tooltip arrow displayed by Chrome to show where the element is located and its size, does not point to the dot itself but several pixels to the right.

So could this be a Chrome issue?

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem? Is there better ways to 'calibrate' the `move_to_element` functionality?

Comment: You could try using getRect() or similar and write your own move_to_element by doing something like x+1, y+1 where x,y is the top left corner. I don't use move_to_element much but from what I remember, it was kinda flaky for me also.